# Present UIViewController above TabBar

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, presentviewcontroller

I am using a TabBarController, and from one of the tabs, I want to present another UIViewController, while keeping the TabBar displayed.

If I simply present or push the view controller, it is displayed in full screen, above the TabBar.

What is the right way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `ViewControllerA` is a `UIViewController` of `TabBarController`. And the `UIViewController` you want to present is `ViewControllerB`

To push `ViewControllerB`, while keeping the TabBar displayed. Simply inside `ViewControllerA` you just need to call

```
ViewControllerB *vc = // Initialize ViewControllerB here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

To present `ViewControllerB`

```
ViewControllerB *vc = Initialize ViewControllerB here
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With presenting, make sure you set `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` for `modalPresentationStyle` property of `ViewControllerB`. If not, it will present fullscreen, over the `TabBar`

For easier understanding, i created [a demo repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/tab-bar-present), you can take a look.